# Form rendering in Symfony2 -- How do I render a 2D Array as a table of checkboxes?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, symfony, checkbox

Maybe my approach to this is not very good (from a data organization standpoint). I am storing a list of permissions for users in the User entity as one field called "permissions" using type=array. The structure of the array will be something like:

```
  Array (
  'Page 1' => Array (
            0 => 'No access',
            1 => 'Read only',
            2 => 'Edit',
            3 => 'Create and Delete')
  'Page n' => Array (
            0 => 'No access',
            1 => 'Read only',
            2 => 'Edit',
            3 => 'Create and Delete')
       )
```

The "Pages" come from another Entity called "Page." I want to be able to render this array as a table similar to how Drupal 7 handles its own User Permissions form: https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/Drupal7Permissions.png

Basically I want to be able to print out a form with table headers "Page, No Access, Read Only, Edit, Create and Delete" and a row structure of "[PAGE NAME], [], [], [], []"

How can this be achieved and have it still be compatible with the Symfony form engine (ie, it reads the array sample I posted above, and it returns that back to the User entity)

Comment: I have a perfectly functioning form to edit the user. It has a field for almost every field in the User entity and it works just fine. I tried adding the extra field : `add('permissions', 'choice', array(
     'required' => false,
     'multiple' => true,
     'expanded' => false,
     'choices' => $user->getPermissions(),
     )` 
And it just rendered a list of checkboxes repeating only the 4 permissions and not displaying the page titles as I expected. I checked the input names and they also didn't have the page name on them. So I figured it doesn't support 2D arrays?

Answer (score 2):

Rendering it directly is not possible, however you can iterate over the array and add a field for each of the elements in the array like so:

```
//Controller
public function DebugAction(Request $request){

    $inputs = Array (
        'Page1' => Array (
             'No access',
             'Read only',
             'Edit',
             'Create and Delete'
        ),
      'Pagen' => Array (
             'No access',
             'Read only',
             'Edit',
             'Create and Delete')
           );


    $form = $this->createFormBuilder();

    foreach($inputs as $title => $values){
        $form->add($title, 'choice', array(
            'choices' => $values,
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => true,
        ));
    }

    $form = $form->getForm();

    return $this->render('debug.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

---

```
{# debug.html.twig #}
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

The above outputs a form that looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problems like this is one of the reasons that I'm slowly moving away from Symfony forms and Twig templates.  Seemingly simple things end up being complicated.  But here is an example of using an included twig template to make a html table of check boxes:

```
{# form.dates is a collection of check boxes #}
{% if form.dates is defined %}
  {# really should have passed items as an argument, oh well #}
  {% set items = form.dates %} 
  <td>{% include '@CeradGame/Project/Schedule/Twig/ScheduleSearchCheckboxes.html.twig' %}</td>
{% endif %}

{# ScheduleSearchCheckboxes.html.twig #}
{# render one set of check boxes as a table #}
{# Setting a class on the first item #}
<table border="1">
  <tr><th colspan="30">{{ items.vars.label }}</th></tr>
  <tr>
  {% set itemFirst = true %}
  {% for item in items %}
    <td align="center">{{ form_label(item) }}<br />
    {% if itemFirst %}
      {{ form_widget(item, { 'attr': {'class': 'cerad-checkbox-all' }}) }}</td>
    {% else %}
      {{ form_widget(item) }}</td>
    {% endif %}
    {% set itemFirst = false %}
  {% endfor %}
  </tr>
</table>
```